# How I can get data from multiple pages with HTML Agility Pack

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, controller, html-agility-pack

Hello I've got a problem with Agility pack in C#. Maybe I don't see somethink what I'm doing wrong.
I want to get movies from multiple pages but when I run my app then getting everythink from 1st page and repeating that n - times (n it's a number what I give). For exaple 10 titles from page is written x4 times in loop

```
bool looping = true;
        string mainUrl = "https://www.filmweb.pl/films/search";
        HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
        HtmlDocument docu = web.Load(mainUrl);
        int inc = 0;

        var tags = docu.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//h2[@class='filmPreview__title']");


        while(looping)
        {
            var nextPage = docu.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@title='następna']/@href").ToList();
            if(inc < 4)
            {
                string link = mainUrl + nextPage[0].Attributes["href"].Value;
                var urlDecode = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(link);
                docu = web.Load(urlDecode);

                

                foreach (var item in tags)
                {
                    Movie mv = new Movie();
                    mv.Tytul = item.InnerText;
                    tytuly.Add(mv);
                }
                inc++;
            }
            else
            {
                looping = false;
            }
        }
```

And below my view code

```
 @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
    <p>@Model[i].Tytul</p>

}
```

I tried with different loops and everytime was same situation. Can you help me? I think I don't see my mistakes

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Only one page is rendered so you cannot get the other pages with that one request. You will have to make multiple requests by editing the querystring to indicate what page you want: `?orderBy=popularity&descending=true&page=2`

Answer (score 0):

There are some logic problem in your codes. You get the films' titles by looping the tags, while the tags are always from the first page, you have not overridden it when you get the new page. I made some changes to your codes, and got the right results

```
bool looping = true;
string mainUrl = "https://www.filmweb.pl/films/search";
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument docu = web.Load(mainUrl);
int inc = 0;
var tags = docu.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//h2[@class='filmPreview__title']");
while (looping)
{
    if (inc < 4)
    {
        foreach (var item in tags)
        {
            Movie mv = new Movie();
            mv.Tytul = item.InnerText;
            tytuly.Add(mv);
        }
        var nextPage = docu.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@title='następna']/@href").ToList();
        string link = mainUrl + nextPage[0].Attributes["href"].Value;
        var urlDecode = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(link);
        docu = web.Load(urlDecode);
        tags = docu.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//h2[@class='filmPreview__title']");
        inc++;
    }
    else
    {
        looping = false;
    }
}
```